# PySpark issue loading json data with schema

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have json data that looks like this (1 object per row):

```
{
  "id": "c428c2e2-c30c-4864-8c12-458ead4b17f5",
  "weight": 73,
  "topics": {
    "type": 1,
    "values": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
}
```

When I read in the data without a specified schema, Spark infers `topics.values` to be an `ArrayType` but I need it to be a `VectorUDT` for doing ML tasks. So I am trying to read in the data set using a schema as follows:

```
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("id", StringType()),
        StructField("weight", IntegerType()),
        StructField("topics", StructType([
            StructField("type", IntegerType()),
            StructField("values", VectorUDT())
        ]))
    ])
```

When I do this I see the type (using `dtype`) of the data frame as follows:

```
[('id', 'string'), ('weight', 'int'), ('topics', 'struct<type:int,values:vector>')]
```

But there seems to be no actual data in the data frame, as show by using `first()`:

```
Row(id=None, weight=None, topics=None)
```

And when I write the data frame to disk, I just see empty braces on each line. Seems odd! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not odd. You pass schema which is not applicable for JSON document.

Comment: @LostInOverflow Can you elaborate? Obviously I am here asking a question because I don't know that.

Comment: @LostInOverflow Well, your comment did make me realize how to do this correctly. So thanks for that.

Comment: Glad it was helpful and sorry I didn't have more definitive suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out:

Just needed to change the schema a bit:

```
schema = StructType([
                StructField("id", StringType()),
                StructField("weight", DoubleType()),
                StructField("topics", VectorUDT())
            ])
```

Now it makes sense.

Comment: whY VectorUDT? Can you explain logic behind it? I checked the documentation here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/VectorUDT.html